# How to get comment metadata of images inside a folder

Tags: php, exif

I want to get `comment` metadata of images inside `../banners` folder

```
$arr = scandir("../banners/");
foreach($arr as $el){
  echo $el;  // this works
  $path = '../banners/' . $el;
  //$arrb = exif_read_data($path, 0, true); // line 91
  $arrb = exif_read_data($path, "COMMENT");  // line 92
  print_r($arrb);
}
```

Result:
If I execute `line 91` everything is listed, but anyway - there is a warning:

`Warning: exif_read_data(): Unable to open file... on line 91`

If I execute `line 92` there is no data but the warning is there:

`Warning: exif_read_data(): Unable to open file... on line 92`

I'm on localhost, windows 7, wamp.

Any help?

Comment: Permissions maybe? Or maybe absolute/relative paths?

Comment: @kerbholz, how to check permissions?

Comment: Talking about file permissions here, depends on the OS you're using, on Linux I usually just do a `ls -l` which results in something like `-rw-r--r--  1 usr user    4 May 26 10:04 composer.json` with `-rw-r--r--` being the permissions

Comment: @kerbholz, I'm on windows 7, localhost, wamp.

Comment: You could also check some of the examples on PHPs [exif_read_data](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) page to see if they work for you.

Comment: No wait, you're using `scandir` which also returns the current directory `.` and the parent directory `..`. In your `foreach` you should filter those out. Or use [glob()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead of `scandir`.

Comment: @kerbholz, see my update, pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scandir()` will return the current directory `.` and the parent directory `..`. You want to filter those out:

```
<?php
$blacklist = ['.', '..'];
$arr = scandir("../banners/");
foreach ($arr as $el) {
    if (!in_array($el, $blacklist)) {
        echo $el;  // this works
        $path = '../banners/' . $el;
        $arrb = exif_read_data($path, "COMMENT");  // line 92
        print_r($arrb);
    }
}
```

I created a `$blacklist` array that holds those values you don't want to be interpreted as images.

Another way could be to use [glob()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead:

```
<?php
foreach (glob('../banners/*.jpg') as $el) {
    echo $el;  // this works
    $path = '../banners/' . $el;
    $arrb = exif_read_data($path, "COMMENT");  // line 92
    print_r($arrb);
}
```

This will return only `*.jpg` without you having to filter out unwanted filetypes/directories.

Comment: I tried, there is no warning, but there is no data also

Comment: Enable error reporting, make sure the file actually has an EXIF comment, view PHP error log etc.

Comment: error reporting is `ON`. Maybe the problem is because I wrote the comments to images (right click on image - details...). This is not comment wiritten by device. But in that case `line 91` should not work also.

Comment: I used GIMP (on Linux though) to edit/add a comment to an image and the code above worked fine.